# GetVolumeInformation returns 0 volume serial number for SD card

Tags: windows

I am using GetVolumeInformation to retrieve the volume serial number and I am encountering cases where on a certain system the value 0 is returned for exFAT formatted SD cards. How can this happen?

The code works in principle as it was tested extensively and verified to return the same results as the "vol" command, e.g.:

C:\Users\Krueger>vol d:
 Volume in drive D is E1
 Volume Serial Number is 3030-3862

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: At mount time, Windows does nothing to ensure that the serial number of a volume is non-zero and unique in the system. When formatting, the serial number is set to a random 32-bit or 64-bit value. It shouldn't be zero, unless something intentionally set it to zero. But zero is allowed and is something you have to be prepared to handle, such as is the case for a WebDAV volume.

Comment: Similarly the file ID is allowed to be 0, and is 0 for all files on a WebDAV volume. IMO, code that uses the (VSN, FileId) as equivalent to Unix (st_dev, st_ino) is dubious. Windows has no simple equivalent.

Comment: I verified that on the user's computer the "vol" command also displays 0000-0000 as serial number for the respective devices, so the code is indeed working correctly. Could this be some kind of security feature erasing this information?

Comment: FYI, the serial number is set in the [volume parameter block](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ns-wdm-_vpb) (VPB) when a volume is mounted by a filesystem. It's a property of the filesystem. Per [exFAT file system specification](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/exfat-specification), it's stored in the main boot region as the 4-byte `VolumeSerialNumber` and "shall (mandatory) contain a unique serial number" and "[i]mplementations should (recommended) generate the serial number by combining the date and time of formatting the exFAT volume".

Comment: Using zero is contrary to the strongly recommended guideline to base the value of the serial number on the date and time of formatting the exFAT volume. And not using a unique value, as zero surely is not, is in violation of the spec.

Comment: But, again, as far as Windows itself is concerned, it allows the serial number to be 0. Note that the VPB documentation states that the `SerialNumber` "member should be set by the file system driver, *if available*". Further, note in [\[MS-FSCC\] 2.5.9 FileFsVolumeInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-fscc/bf691378-c34e-4a13-976e-404ea1a87738) that the serial number is "not required to be unique" and a zero value is not disallowed.